# How to use unique_ptr with operator new

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, new-operator, unique-ptr

I am allocating a piece of scratch memory with input size, and I'd like to use a `unique_ptr` to track proper lifetime without having to explicitly worry about freeing it myself. This is what I came up with:

```
{
    std::unique_ptr<BYTE> sp;
    sp.reset(reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(operator new (100)));
}
```

I had to use a `BYTE` since MSVC won't compile with `std::unique_ptr<void>`. From my testing, the `new` and `delete` operators are called as expected. Since this is a bit of an uncommon usage (i.e. using `operator new` explicitly), I wanted to check that there's nothing wrong with this? And whether there's any alternatives that may be better/cleaner?

Comment: Why would you do this over just saying "new BYTE[100]" ? Also, static_cast is sufficient to cast from `void*` to an object pointer type.

Comment: Not sure why you wouldn't just use a vector.

Comment: @ Billy. That's a good point. Other than overloading the operator, is it always possible to do what operator new (x) can do via new BYTE[x]?

Comment: @lancery Not exactly sure what you mean by your last comment, but `operator new(N)` allocates N bytes for you, that's it. `new T[N]` will allocate `sizeof(T) * N` bytes and then construct N copies of T in the allocated memory. For a built-in type like `BYTE` (typdef for `unsigned char`, assuming this is the WinAPI `BYTE`), the constructor is a NOP, so they both do the same thing in this case.

Comment: @lancery: As far as I am aware, yes. Note that `unique_ptr<void>` does not compile because doing so would always cause undefined behavior. `unique_ptr` calls `delete`. Calling delete on `void*` is undefined behavior; the standard requires that the type of pointer passed to `delete` match that of `new`. `char* foo = new char[42]; delete[] foo; // OK` , `int* foo = reinterpret_cast<int*>(new char[42]); delete[] foo; // Undefined behavior` `void* foo = reinterpret_cast<void*>(new char[42]); delete[] foo; // Undefined behavior` See C++11 `5.3.5 [expr.delete]/1-2`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you want to dynamically allocate an array using `new[]`, you must use the `unique_ptr` partial specialization for array types. Otherwise a `unique_ptr` will call `delete` on the array, instead of `delete[]`, when it goes out of scope, which would be undefined behavior. Use this:

```
std::unique_ptr<BYTE[]> sp(new BYTE[100]);
```

And if you're using VS2013, you can even avoid the call to `new` by using `make_unique`.

```
auto sp = make_unique<BYTE[]>(100);
```

Note that the `make_unique` version will zero-initialize the array, while the first version won't.

---

If you really intended to use `operator new`, then you'll need to provide a custom deleter that will call `operator delete` to free the memory.

```
std::unique_ptr<BYTE, void(*)(BYTE *)> sp(static_cast<BYTE *>(::operator new(100)),
                                          [](BYTE *p) { ::operator delete(p);} );
```

Comment: Yeah, but isn't that his intent? *I am allocating a piece of scratch memory* - sounds like he wants to allocate an array.

Comment: Are you saying that with the way my code is structured, it won't delete properly?

Comment: @lancery It won't because a `unique_ptr` uses [`std::default_delete`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete) by default for deallocation, which in turn will call `delete ptr;` on the managed pointer. You want `::operator delete(ptr)` to be called instead.

Comment: @lancery In case of a built-in type, there is no difference between `new[]` and `operator new`. I do see what you're saying, but making the distinction is not worth the effort, IMHO. Just compare the verbosity of the `operator new` method to `make_unique`. Also, in my last comment, instead of *it won't work*, I should've said it's undefined behavior to call `delete` instead of `operator delete` on a piece of memory you allocated using `operator new`

Comment: @ Praetorian EDITED: I didn't opt to use the `new []` because to me conceptually, there's a difference between a pointer to memory that I will copy random contents in, versus a pointer to an array, which are indexed and utilized per element. I mean, it just seems a little weird to do things like copying the contents of a struct to an array, whereas it seems perfectly logical for a pointer to memory...but maybe that's just me.

Comment: @lancery: An array of bytes is how you say "memory" in C. A managed (by `unique_ptr` or `vector` or whatever) array of bytes is how you say "memory" in C++. If you want the Nth byte of memory, that's `sp[N]`.

Comment: Note that your `make_unique` expression is semantically different because it initializes the array.